# How to take diff of two directories and apply the created patch to original one?

Tags: linux

I am newbie to using diff.  I wish to create a patch to content of a directory recursively and give it to some one so that he could patch to a directory(slightly different) with him. Thanks in advance. Would be glad if some can clarify me as to how can I make it possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a patch using something like

```
diff -cr originaldirectory/ updateddirectory/ > your.patch
```

And apply using

```
patch -p0 -i your.patch
```

Comment: Thanks.
I would like to know what does -p0 stand for ??
Also when I apply patch I need to enter y as many times the files in which changes are required. This is the question which prompts :
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]

Not sure what does signify as I dint apply any patch before running the command. Can it be made simpler ??

Comment: p0 just tells it not to strip any slashes, check your manual. And that sounds like you are applying the patch on your machine instead of the one to be patched.